# AWS Polly Java Client gives error: Unable to load region information from any provider in the chain

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-polly

I am using the JAVA SDK from AWS to create a Polly client.
Like this:

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("<IAM access Key>", "IAM secret key>");

    AmazonPollyClient apClient = (AmazonPollyClient) AmazonPollyClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
            .build();


    SynthesizeSpeechRequest tssRequest = new SynthesizeSpeechRequest();
    tssRequest.setText(<text>);
    tssRequest.setVoiceId(<voiceid>);
    tssRequest.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mp3);
    SynthesizeSpeechResult tssResult = apClient.synthesizeSpeech(tssRequest);
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to
>   load region information from any provider in the chain    at
>   com.amazonaws.regions.AwsRegionProviderChain.getRegion(AwsRegionProviderChain.java:56)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:319)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:295)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:38)
>     at com.eoffice.aws.speech.Polly.main(Polly.java:42)

I checked the credentials using the IAM Policy Simulator. This works fine, permissions are OK.

The method to set the Region in the ClientBuilder is NOT visible for the AmazonPollyClientBuilder, so I have no (Java SDK) way to specify the region.

**Update:**
When I just ask the defaultAwsREgionProviderChain, I get the same error message

```
DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain defaultAwsRegionProviderChain = new DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain();
System.out.println(defaultAwsRegionProviderChain.getRegion());
```

**Updat 2:**
When I create a config file in de .aws folder with the following content:

> [default] 
>   region = eu-west-1

It works, but I need a way to set this without relying on the file system.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Providing a System Environment variable with name "AWS_REGION" did the trick.
See screenshot for configuration in IBM Bluemix

[image]

Comment: in my case even after setting the environment variable I had to restart netbeans for it to take effect

Answer (score 5):

I think you can set Region like this

```
AmazonPollyClient apClient = (AmazonPollyClient) AmazonPollyClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds)).withRegion("<aws-region>").build();
```

Comment: Or better still - `.withRegion(Region.US_WEST_1)` for example.