# Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I tried setting up a user like this:

```
aws configure --profile MyUser
```

and activate it via:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=MyUser
```

However, I keep getting the following exception:

> May 20, 2018 3:09:02 PM com.amazonaws.auth.profile.internal.BasicProfileConfigLoader loadProfiles
>
> WARNING: The legacy profile format requires the 'profile ' prefix before the profile name. The latest code does not require such prefix, and will consider it as part of the profile name. Please remove the prefix if you are seeing this warning.
>
> Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.

It is strange that if I configure it with the default user, then everything is working fine:

```
aws configure
```

**Why isn't configuration with a specific username doesn't work above?**

---

I also know that we can configure the credential in code like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45081648/1035008) or this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43246921/1035008).

```
AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3Client.builder()
    .withRegion("us-east-1")
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
    .build();
```

That works, but I just think it is a bad idea to put credentials in source code and check them in with git.

---

Also from the error message, it looks like I am using an old format with `profile` in the prefix name (as described in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43790708/1035008). I've double checked the `aws-cli` version and make sure that it is up-to-date also double checked that I don't have the prefix in the profile name.

Here is about the version:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.129 Python/3.6.2 Darwin/17.5.0 botocore/1.5.92
```

And here is the configuration file:

```
cat ~/.aws/credentials             
[default]
aws_access_key_id = A***
aws_secret_access_key = I***
[MyUser]
aws_access_key_id = A***
aws_secret_access_key = D***
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just figure out what's wrong. There are two files generated with `aws configure --profile MyUser`.

- ~/.aws/config
- ~/.aws/credential

I notice that the generated config file does have `profile` in the prefix

```
$ cat ~/.aws/config 
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json
[profile MyUser]
region = us-west-1
output = json
```

After removing that, things work perfectly:

```
[MyUser]
region = us-west-1
output = json
```

---

Alternatively, we can specify the credential configuration file and the user explicitly. As an example, in Scala:

```
private lazy val credential =
    new ProfileCredentialsProvider("/Users/yuchen/.aws/credentials", "MyUser")

private lazy val lambda = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
    .withCredentials(credential)
    .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_1)
    .build()
```

Comment: It is rather odd that this aws command configures the config file wrongly.

Comment: Apparently, it's the AWS Java SDK that is wrong, and this behavior [will be fixed in V2 of the AWS Java SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1083#issuecomment-331993784) so that it handles `[profile MyUser]` inside of `~/.aws/config` correctly.